# Compare EXCEL files with Python

Tags: python, excel, comparison

I have two rate files (rate for international long distance), say rate_a a and rate_b in EXCEL files.

I like to compare the rates of  two files country by country, code by code, and get to which country rate_a’s rate is cheaper the rate_b’s rate.
I like to do this with python (maybe pandas).

For example two files below:

what I want :

from rate_a file , start from first code 9370 to check rate_b file to see if rate_b also has this code 9370,
If rate_b also has this 9370, then compare the rate, if rate_a’s rate is lower , then set the forth column “comparison” as “true”, then compare second code 9379 and so…until all codes are compared.
the challenging part is two files’s code break down is different.

```
rate_a:
destination code    rate
AFGHANISTAN - MOBILE - AWCC 9370    0.2712
AFGHANISTAN - MOBILE - CDMA 9375    0.2552
AFGHANISTAN - MOBILE - MTN  9377    0.1914
AFGHANISTAN - MOBILE - OTHER CARRIERS   9378    0.1627
AFGHANISTAN - MOBILE - ROSHAN   9379    0.2313
AFGHANISTAN - PROPER    93  0.3111
AFGHANISTAN - PROPER    937 0.2912
AFGHANISTAN - PROPER    9371    0.2712
AFGHANISTAN - PROPER    9372    0.2313
AFGHANISTAN - PROPER    9373    0.1627
AFGHANISTAN - PROPER    9374    0.2329
AFGHANISTAN - PROPER    9376    0.1914
ALBANIA - MOBILE - AMC  35568   0.5822
ALBANIA - MOBILE - EAGLE    35567   0.5663
ALBANIA - MOBILE - VODAFONE 35569   0.5822
ALBANIA - PROPER    35536073    0.2532
ALBANIA - PROPER    35536340    0.2532
ALBANIA - PROPER    35536290    0.2532
ALBANIA - PROPER    35536240    0.2532
ALBANIA - PROPER    35536150    0.2532
ALBANIA - PROPER    35536090    0.2532
ALBANIA - PROPER    3552185 0.2532
ALBANIA - PROPER    35536063    0.2532
ALBANIA - PROPER    35529750    0.2532
ALBANIA - PROPER    35529570    0.2532
ALBANIA - PROPER    35529590    0.2532
ALBANIA - PROPER    35529623    0.2532
ALBANIA - PROPER    35529650    0.2532
ALBANIA - PROPER    35529680    0.2532
ALBANIA - PROPER    35529723    0.2532
ALBANIA - PROPER    35529763    0.2532
ALBANIA - PROPER    35536043    0.2532

Rate_b:
destination code    rate
AFGHANISTAN - MOBILE - AWCC 9370    0.2712
AFGHANISTAN - MOBILE - CDMA 9375    0.2552
AFGHANISTAN - MOBILE - MTN  9377    0.1914
AFGHANISTAN - MOBILE - OTHER CARRIERS   9378    0.1627
AFGHANISTAN - MOBILE - ROSHAN   9379    0.2313
AFGHANISTAN - PROPER    93  0.3111
AFGHANISTAN - PROPER    937 0.2912
AFGHANISTAN - PROPER    9371    0.2712
AFGHANISTAN - PROPER    9372    0.2313
AFGHANISTAN - PROPER    9373    0.1627
AFGHANISTAN - PROPER    9374    0.2329
AFGHANISTAN - PROPER    9376    0.1914
ALBANIA - MOBILE - AMC  35568   0.5822
ALBANIA - MOBILE - EAGLE    35567   0.5663
ALBANIA - MOBILE - VODAFONE 35569   0.5822
ALBANIA - PROPER    35536073    0.2532
ALBANIA - PROPER    35536340    0.2532
ALBANIA - PROPER    35536290    0.2532
ALBANIA - PROPER    35536240    0.2532
ALBANIA - PROPER    35536150    0.2532
ALBANIA - PROPER    35536090    0.2532
ALBANIA - PROPER    3552185 0.2532
ALBANIA - PROPER    35536063    0.2532
ALBANIA - PROPER    35529750    0.2532
ALBANIA - PROPER    35529570    0.2532
ALBANIA - PROPER    35529590    0.2532
ALBANIA - PROPER    35529623    0.2532
ALBANIA - PROPER    35529650    0.2532
ALBANIA - PROPER    35529680    0.2532
ALBANIA - PROPER    35529723    0.2532
ALBANIA - PROPER    35529763    0.2532
```

[rate_a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv1wV.png)

[rete_b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkZg5.png)

Comment: So, you need to read two files, interpret their contents correctly, get them into the data structure you prefer (like a DataFrame as you suggest) and run the comparison. Don't expect SO to write your code for you, but once you've given it a shot, come here asking about specific problems if you run into any.

Comment: sorry, I posted rate_a file image incorrectly, rate_a and rate_b country codes break down if different, but i could not edit my post to correct it.
No place I can edit my post.
rate_a
destination codes rate
AFGHANISTAN-MOBILE 9370 0.2601
AFGHANISTAN-MOBILE 9379 0.2601
AFGHANISTAN-ROC 93 0.2896
ALBANIA-MOBILE AMC 35568 0.5482
ALBANIA-MOBILE EAGLE 35567 0.5890
ALBANIA-MOBILE PLUS 35566 0.6087
ALBANIA-MOBILE VODAFONE 35569 0.5482
ALBANIA-OLO 35588199 0.2221
ALBANIA-OLO 35588220 0.2221